# Parse a ruby object sent from a form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, object

I'm trying to pass an object through a form like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for :export, url: export_path(format: :xls,data: @result) do |f| %>
 ### fields
<% end %>
```

But I'm getting the object as a string and so I'm not able to access it. How do I convert the passed string to object?

I'm getting:

> undefined method `something` for "Mongoid::Criteria:0x00000105f75818":String

**Update**

I found out that this is a really bad way of passing object via a form. Instead, I sent all the `id`'s concerning the `@result` object and recreated the `result` object server side. That solved my problem.

Comment: `But I'm getting the object as a string` ?? Which object, do you mean `@result`? If thats true then what do you store in `@result`? Is it an  Model instance? Also, share the relevant action in code and also the server log generated upon form submission.

Comment: It's a query on a model. For ex. `@result = Model.where(....)` or `@result = Model.all`

Comment: why are you doing this?

Comment: I want to export the "contents" of `@result` object to excel and the form field selects the columns which I need to export.

Comment: @mrudult You partially answered my question. Read it again. And supply the required information

Comment: @KirtiThorat check my second comment.

Comment: Without looking at relevant code, I will go with the way how emaillenin answered. And his approach is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few options for you:

- Don't send the @result via form. Have it in the server(as file/database record) and read only the column list from the form
- Use only the required string portion of @result in your form
- If you need the entire object, serialize your @result object and pass via form. Deserialize back in the server. Use something like [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Marshal.html).

Comment: @emaillenin point 3 worked perfect. Thanks. I used ruby's [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Marshal.html)